# Laravel validate array input

Tags: validation, laravel

I'm trying to build some custom grid forms which looks like

```
form.blade.php
<table>
   <tr>
      <td>
        {{ Form::text('name[]', null, array('placeholder' => 'name') }}
      </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>
        {{ Form::text('aerobic[]', null, array('placeholder' => 'aerobic') }}
      </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>
        {{ Form::text('core_test[]', null, array('placeholder' => 'core test') }}
      </td>
   </tr>
</table>

Validation rules
$validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), array(
        'name[]' => 'required|alpha',
        'aerobic[]' => 'required|alpha',
        'core_test[]' => 'required|alpha'
    ));
```

How do I validate the inputs or what other good ways would be to build this?

I get the following errors when I submit the form

```
htmlentities() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given 
(View: /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/hp/v1.1/app/views
/files/templates/apa/form.blade.php)
```

I've also tried this

```
$validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), array(
        'name' => 'required|alpha',
        'aerobic' => 'required|alpha',
        'core_test' => 'required|alpha'
    ));
```

And I get this error from alpha validation rule

```
preg_match() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given
```

Comment: wouldn't is_array($yourvariable) be sufficient ?

Comment: @astro where would I use is_array on which part of the code

Comment: You should use the latter version of rules `name`, not `name[]`. Then you can use builtin rule `array` which makes sure that passed value is an array. Unfortunately, there is no builtin method for validating items of that array, so you need a custom rule.

Comment: sorry i didnt see the [] in input name. laravel's validation cannot process values inside an arrays as i know. you can try with a custom validation rule to iterate through the array and validate http://laravel.com/docs/validation#custom-validation-rules a preg_match in side the loop would do the trick

Answer (score 0):

I've spend a lot of time trying to figure out how to solve this problem...Laravel does not expect a text input to be an array. so you either use plain html for your array inputs, or use [custom macros](https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.1/html#custom-macros) to create your own form class(I assume you're using `LaravelCollective`).

Answer (score -3):

Take off the `[]` in the name of each of your inputs. PHP is interpreting those inputs as arrays instead of strings.

Example:

```
{{ Form::text('name', null, array('placeholder' => 'Name')) }}
```

Comment: but I have 10 rows on each column with the same name like name[] X 10 rows, if I take it off when the validation fails it won't refill the old values

Comment: I want to be able to use it like multiple checkboxes

Comment: Oh, right. Didn't catch that part sorry. Laravel doesn't have good support for array validations at this point in time. You'd be best off writing your own extension for the validator (read the docs) or validate another way unfortunately.